# How to add data to a dictionary in a specific format?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an empty dictionary to begin with:

```
dict = {}
```

I have some data I want to put into that dictionary:

```
sample_list = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7]]
```

And I need it in a format like this:

```
dict = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [3,4,5], 'key3': [5,6,7]}
```

I tried different things... never works like I planned it.
This is, kinda, the best solution that I came up with, but the problem is, it replaces a value every time.

```
for item in sample_list:
    for i in item:
        dict[str(item)] = i
```

In the end I left with:

```
dict{'1,2,3': 3, '3,4,5': 5, '5,6,7': 7}
```

but I want:

```
dict{'1,2,3': [1,2,3], '3,4,5': [3,4,5], '5,6,7': [5,6,7]}
```

Comment: Please format the code first so that it is easy to read.

Comment: remove `for i in item:` and change ` dict[str(item)] = i` to ` dict[str(item)] = item`

Answer (score 4):

If that's the output you want, this should work:

```
for item in sample_list: 
    dict[str(item)] = item
```

Comment: wow, super simple and works, thanks a lot. How on Earth I didn't think about myself :)

Comment: Actually, this has a bug: the `[]` brackets should not be included in the key.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, using a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = { str(item)[1:-1]: item for item in sample_list }
```

By the way, it's a bad idea to call a variable `dict`, that clashes with the built-in `dict()` function.

Comment: There is a difference in `'[1,2,3]'` and `'1,2,3'`

Answer (score 2):

Dict comprehension

```
{','.join(map(str,item)):item for item in sample_list}
```

Output

```
{'1,2,3': [1,2,3], '3,4,5': [3,4,5], '5,6,7': [5,6,7]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output as you described at the top it you can use enumerate:

```
sample_list = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7]]
output = {}

for num, sublist in enumerate(sample_list):
    output["key{}".format(num)] = sublist
```

If you want the output how it looks at the end you need to covert the lists into strings (only immutable objects can be keys in dictionaries - strings, not lists)

```
sample_list = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7]]
output = {}

for sublist in sample_list:
    output[str(sublist)] = sublist
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
dict = { f"key{index+1}":item for index,item in enumerate(sample_list) }

# {'key1': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [3, 4, 5], 'key3': [5, 6, 7]}
```